# Python 3.6 and paramiko

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko

Trying to use `paramiko library` with `Python 3.6` and I get stuck at the simple code snippet possible. Trying to connect from my `Linux` host to my `Windows` host (ssh server is running and I can connect via terminal) I get this error:

```
SSHException: Channel closed.
```

Code:

```
@keyword('Open Connection And Log In ${host} ${port} ${username} ${pwd}')
def open_connection_and_login(host, port, username, pwd):
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(host, port=22, username='root', password='root')
    command = 'dir'
    (stdin, stdout, stderr) = client.exec_command(command)

    print(stdout.read())
    client.close()
```

Traceback:

```
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/matejb/Development/automated-testing/python_libs/topit/ssh/basicOperations.py", line 13, in open_connection_and_login
    (stdin, stdout, stderr) = client.exec_command(command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 478, in exec_command
    chan.exec_command(command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 63, in _check
    return func(self, *args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 241, in exec_command
    self._wait_for_event()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 1197, in _wait_for_event
    raise e
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Channel closed.
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/matejb/Development/automated-testing/python_libs/topit/ssh/basicOperations.py", line 13, in open_connection_and_login
    (stdin, stdout, stderr) = client.exec_command(command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 478, in exec_command
    chan.exec_command(command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 63, in _check
    return func(self, *args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 241, in exec_command
    self._wait_for_event()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 1197, in _wait_for_event
    raise e
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Channel closed.
```

More log:

```
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0x10223668
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.3.1
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-WeOnlyDo 2.4.3
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client WeOnlyDo)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos:['ecdh-sha2-nistp256', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp521', 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1'] server key:['ssh-rsa', 'ssh-dss'] client encrypt:['aes128-cbc', 'aes128-ctr', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-cbc', 'aes256-ctr', 'rijndael128-cbc', 'rijndael192-cbc', 'rijndael256-cbc', 'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se', 'cast128-cbc'] server encrypt:['aes128-cbc', 'aes128-ctr', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-cbc', 'aes256-ctr', 'rijndael128-cbc', 'rijndael192-cbc', 'rijndael256-cbc', 'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se', 'cast128-cbc'] client mac:['hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-sha1', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5', 'none'] server mac:['hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-sha1', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5', 'none'] client compress:['none', 'none'] server compress:['none', 'none'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Kex agreed: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:HostKey agreed: ssh-rsa
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:MAC agreed: hmac-sha2-256
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Compression agreed: none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex engine KexNistp256 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to new keys ...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Adding ssh-rsa host key for 10.99.2.20: b'eea39f0acdfb5c2b7d042887e668ebac'
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying SSH agent key b'e440c2d0b5fb98ab3951ddc52c4ba86b'
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) failed.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying discovered key b'e440c2d0b5fb98ab3951ddc52c4ba86b' in /home/matejb/.ssh/id_rsa
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) failed.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (password) successful!
<function basicConfig at 0x7f9311f11950>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Max packet out: 98304 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Secsh channel 0 opened.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] EOF sent (0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/matejb/Development/automated-testing/python_libs/topit/ssh/basicOperations.py", line 17, in open_connection_and_login
    client.open_sftp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 513, in open_sftp
    return self._transport.open_sftp_client()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 978, in open_sftp_client
    return SFTPClient.from_transport(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 138, in from_transport
    chan.invoke_subsystem('sftp')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 63, in _check
    return func(self, *args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 267, in invoke_subsystem
    self._wait_for_event()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 1197, in _wait_for_event
    raise e
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Channel closed.
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/matejb/Development/automated-testing/python_libs/topit/ssh/basicOperations.py", line 17, in open_connection_and_login
    client.open_sftp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 513, in open_sftp
    return self._transport.open_sftp_client()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 978, in open_sftp_client
    return SFTPClient.from_transport(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 138, in from_transport
    chan.invoke_subsystem('sftp')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 63, in _check
    return func(self, *args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 267, in invoke_subsystem
    self._wait_for_event()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 1197, in _wait_for_event
    raise e
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Channel closed.
```

Comment: Please provide the whole traceback.

Comment: See edited post

Comment: Could you try `sftp user@windows_host`? It seems a problem caused by server.

Comment: connects fine and right away

Comment: OK, you can use `logging.getLogger("paramiko").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` to enable additional debug info. I think we need more information.

Comment: Enabled the logger but the stack has the same info....

Comment: What ssh server are you running on your windows host? I've had this issue before when I tried to use a plain ssh connection, and the server only understood sftp. You need to use `client.open_sftp()` in that case, which returns an sftp channel which you can communicate over.

Comment: I am using the integrated ssh server inside windows10

Comment: client.open_sftp() does not have any effect

Comment: strange... no more info? Maybe you need to call `logging.basicConfig` first?

Comment: Not sure if i understand this logging... How can I do this?

Comment: Added more logging information

Comment: Try another SSH client library like libssh2, python wrapper at [ssh2-python](https://github.com/ParallelSSH/ssh2-python) or a higher level library using it like [parallel-ssh](https://github.com/ParallelSSH/parallel-ssh) (use client `from pssh.pssh2_client`). I do not have access to a Win10 machine to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the missing package throwing the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'` ?

Otherwise, if the problem is located on the server not allowing specific command executions, you might have to take a look there at the error code..